# What is the point of learning the method puts in Ruby when it is hardly used in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After doing a couple of rails tutorials, I've realized that the method `puts` is not used at all.

I am wondering what the point was to learn `puts` in Ruby as every Ruby tutorial seems to teach it...

Or will there be more opportunities to use `puts` as I get into advanced Rails?

Comment: rails != ruby. `puts` is a very useful method. How else are you going to print stuff to terminal?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev So are you saying it is used mainly for like debug purposes?

Comment: No, it's used mainly for printing to terminal. What do you use that output for, debug or something else - it's up to you. For example, in a background job processor you don't have any other channel of communication. Either stdout or logfile.

Comment: In pretty much any language, there's going to be a way to print output. You can't really say you know a language without knowing basic things like this. While it could be used for debugging, there are better ways (search for debugger gems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is a programming language and Rails is a framework.

There are various methods and syntax you have to learn in Ruby using which you can work in Rails.

Regarding `puts`, it's mostly used in rails for printing the values in terminal.

Comment: hmmm interesting...could you give me an example of when someone would want to print out a value in the terminal?

Comment: suppose you calling a function in rails and want to print the values which comes in that function then you can use `puts` code: def func(a) puts "value: #{a}" end

Comment: whenever user hits a url, request goes to rails controller and using `puts` to can get the parameter which user pass and it prints in termial

Comment: ok so its used for like debugging and sort of making sure something is working properly.

Comment: @Robert yes mainly its used for debugging but you can use it for other purpose also..like to display some message when developer run some command

Comment: `puts` is used to display any message on terminal...message is anything

Comment: @Robert: IRb, Pry, the Rails Console, the `rails` command, `rspec`, `cucumber`, they all print to the console. How do you think they do that?